# Hibernate ScrollableResults without transaction

Tags: hibernate, scrollableresults

I have a piece of code that iterate a ScrollableResults and do some calculation on each element.
The iteration is surrounded by transaction.

```
 EntityTransaction transaction = emf.createEntityManager().getTransaction();
 transaction.begin();
 ScrollableResults scrollableResults = em.unwrap(Session.class).createQuery("my select query").scroll();

    while (scrollableResults.next()){
        MyEntity entity= (MyEntity) scrollableResults.get(0);
        someCalculation(entity);
    }

    transaction.commit();
    em.close();
```

I use ScrollableResults since I don't want to load all items to memory on the other hand I don't want to keep the transaction open for a long time since the iteration may take some time.
I omitted the begin and commit transaction and I was still able to iterate the resultSet.
What is the best solution for this kind of scenario ?
Should I keep the transaction open for a long time or not using transaction at all?

Comment: Let's keep the discussion on the Hibernate discourse forum: https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/hibernate-scrollableresults-without-transaction/5491/4